# Voice call recording Android 7.0 in samsung 8

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, audio-recording, mediarecorder, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to record the voice call through `MediaRecorder`. This not working `android 7.0` but below `android 6` its working perfectly. Can some suggest is there any way to record in `android 7` phone.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
  //recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); //I tried all values here
                        recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(8000);
  recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
  recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
  recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
  recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
  try {
   recorder.prepare();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  recorder.start();
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html#audio-record-permission BTW not working is not a error description.

Comment: I was given all permission runtime. Its just creating the file with empty voice.

Answer (score 0):

Call recording is a special case which does not obey the same permissions or code paths. [See this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/194839/how-to-record-a-call-on-your-android-phone/). It seems to be deliberately made more difficult to do.

Comment: I am expecting to record from my application not from other GoogleVoice/Call Recorder – ACR.